# No publication number?

Tags: patent-applications, uspto, search

What does it mean if both the "Earliest Publication No:" and "Earliest Publication Date:" entries in publicpair are blank ("-")? As a follow-up, how would I go about finding the publication number for such a patent (I've tried Google and all and no tangible results pop up), if there is one even?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please list the patent number.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in regard to your other question, publication is a relatively new phenomena and it can be avoided by election of the applicant in some circumstances.